# Mapping quantum states of different (quantum) physical systems to the same Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space

Is it possible to map quantum states of different physical (quantum) systems to the same Hilbert space? For example if I consider two different molecules  in the ground state, may I represent them as kets in the same Hilbert space? I am not considering to construct a tensor product of their own Hilbert spaces like in the case of composite systems.

If I am not wrong, I recall that in S matrix scattering theory, different colliding particle are mapped to kets in the same Hilbert space.

If it is correct, may I think that a mixture state of a quantum system is a result of a statistical ensemble of states of different (quantum) physical systems?

Comment: *"I am not considering to construct a tensor product of their own Hilbert spaces like in the case of composite systems."* Why, uh, not? (If the systems are non-interacting, you won't get entangled states, but it still works)

Comment: No, they are not interacting. I want to know if different systems can be represented by kets in the same Hilbert space.

Comment: You didn't answer why you think the tensor product unsuitable for this.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your question. I want to know if in principle a Hilbert space can accomodate  quantum states of different systems with similar degrees of freedom.

Comment: I added a question mark to the last sentence of the post. Please use correct punctuation; it helps readers understand the question and offer good answers.